# How to retrieve Child objects using ParentId in quickblox iOS

Tags: ios, quickblox, parentid, child-objects

i wanted to retrieve all child objects using Parentid from QuickBlox API.How can i do that.Can anyone suggest the proper way of doing that in ios platform.

Answer (score 0):

You should use method

```
+ (QB_NONNULL QBRequest *)objectsWithClassName:(QB_NONNULL NSString *)className
                           extendedRequest:(QB_NULLABLE NSMutableDictionary QB_GENERIC(NSString *, NSString *) *)extendedRequest
                              successBlock:(QB_NULLABLE void (^)(QBResponse *QB_NONNULL_S response, NSArray QB_GENERIC(QBCOCustomObject *) *QB_NULLABLE_S objects, QBResponsePage *QB_NULLABLE_S page))successBlock
                                errorBlock:(QB_NULLABLE QBRequestErrorBlock)errorBlock;
```

with extendedRequest like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *extendedRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[requestParameters setObject:parendID forKey:@"_parent_id"];
```